AWS Lambda dependency issue with botocore/awscrt
I have a lambda function in python which worked good for a while.
I tried to add CloudFront keyValueStore to the function and locally i got into an error:
[ERROR] MissingDependencyException: Missing Dependency: This operation requires an additional dependency. Use pip install botocore[crt] before proceeding.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 56, in lambda_handler
    upload_files(env, client, zip_file_path, parts[-1], user_name)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 125, in upload_files
    update_keyvaluestore(env, client, values)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 239, in update_keyvaluestore
    e_tag = cloudfront_keyvaluestore_client.describe_key_value_store(
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 967, in _make_api_call
    ) = self._resolve_endpoint_ruleset(
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 1130, in _resolve_endpoint_ruleset
    auth_info = self._ruleset_resolver.auth_schemes_to_signing_ctx(
  File "/var/task/botocore/regions.py", line 711, in auth_schemes_to_signing_ctx
    raise MissingDependencyException(

Locally i've manage to solve this by doing pip install awscrt
But, when i created the new zip with the new dependency - i run into the same error.
I've already tried to add botocore, awscrt, boto3 folders to the zip file with all the dependencies, but it still not working.

I had a similar error with nodejs. At the end I had to switch to a docker image with all my dependencies  instead the basic lambda editor

What version of AWS CLI, python and SAM CLI are you using? Also, what is your computer's chip architecture (x64_x86 or ARM64) vs what is the chip architecture configured on the function? What OS are you using to develop this (Windows, linux or mac?)

@AllanChua
Hey, Thanks!
On lambda function - Python 3.10, x86_64 using the AWS console.
Locally - Python 3.9.6, Apple M2, Mac.

@TomerFikler, it seems you are experiencing some binary conflict between between the x86_64 runtime architecture and your dev machine's ARM64 chips. Could you try switching your Lambda function's chip architecture to arm64 to check if it fixes the problem your problem? Also, it seems that the SAM CLI repository included a recent fix at the version 1.117.0 which is related to openSSL installers. Could you try installing the latest version to 1.118.0?

@AllanChua
I changed to arm64 on the lambda, besides it take more time - it fails with the same error.
Couldn't find out where to configure the SAM CLI on the lambda function..
Thanks!

We managed to fix it after long investigation.
When creating a client you should add a config signature version 4.
for examples:
in python:
from botocore.config import Config
my_config = Config(
        signature_version='v4',
    )
cloudfront_keyvaluestore_client = boto3.client('cloudfront-keyvaluestore', config=my_config, region_name='us-east-1')

in NodeJS:
import '@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt';
import { SignatureV4MultiRegion } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4-multi-region';
const cloudFrontClient = new CloudFrontKeyValueStoreClient({
    region: REGION,
    signerConstructor: SignatureV4MultiRegion,
});

Thanks for the help!
